# To call a button from another button in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to call a button from another button in access via event procedure any suggestion how to achieve this?

For e.g i have three buttons a b and c. so

when c is pressed it trigger A and B buttons as well in MS Access 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With little trick ..

In your Btn C Click event

```
  btnA.SetFocus
  Call SendKeys(" ",True)
  btnB.SetFocus
  Call SendKeys(" ",True)
```

Answer (score 1):

As noticed already, you can simply `Call from.button_Click`.

However, maybe you should modularize your code. If button C also triggers functionality from button A and B, why not create functions for shared code and call them?

Code in same form, module, other form, wherever it makes more sense:

```
Public Function funcA()
    '... (Shared code from button A)
End Function

Public Function funcB()
    '... (Shared code from button B)
End Function
```

Code in form:

```
Private Sub ButtonA_Click()
    Call funcA
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonB_Click()
    Call funcB
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonC_Click()
    '... (Specific code from button C)
    Call funcA
    Call funcB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, your Click procedure needs to be Public rather than Private. Then the following syntax will work:

```
Call Forms.frmForm1.button1_Click
```

Using your FormName and ControlName of course!

[Source :](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=101580)